# How to install an apk once downloaded in app, or pop up requesting install?

Tags: android, html, installation, download, apk

I have created a html page with tables that lists android apks.

I also have an APK which displays the html page, when clicking the download button it downloads the chosen APK... Perfect!

What I want to do is once the download is complete it requests to install the application.

I've tried a few things but it's too much for me to do, would anyone mind helping for some beer tokens,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `BroadcastReceiver` as a callback when your download completes , and then call the following method inside that callback-

```
public static void installapk(File apkFile, Context context) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            if (apkFile.exists()) {
                Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                install.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    install.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(apkFile),
                            "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                    Uri apkUri =
                            FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.yourcompany.yourapp.fileprovider", apkFile);
                    install.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                    install.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                    install.setDataAndType(apkUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                    context.startActivity(install);

                } else {
                    install.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    install.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(apkFile),
                            "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                    context.startActivity(install);
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("apk doesnot exist.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Don't forget to add this permission in your AndroidManifest.xml file -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```

You also need to create a fileprovider authority in your AndroidManifest.xml -

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
        </provider>
```

Then Create a new xml File inside res/xml folder named file_paths.xml and paste this code -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external"
        path="." />
    <external-files-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

Happy Coding!